# React and TypeScript, getting "Type expected" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am converting a React component into Typescript (*.ts) from JS. It is giving the error below "Type expected". How would I fix this?

```
const SisenseDashboard = () => {

  const sisenseRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        alignItems="center"
        marginBottom={2}
      >
        <h2>In-App Reporting</h2>
      </Box>
      <Box
        ref={sisenseRef}
        id="sisense-container"
        className="sisense-demo"
      ></Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure your component file extension is `.tsx` and not `.ts`. This should resolve your issue. Addinonnaly, you could tell TypeScript that your function is a React Functional Component, for example, with the help of the `FC` type from React:

```
import {FC} from "react";

const SisenseDashboard : FC = () => {

  const sisenseRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        alignItems="center"
        marginBottom={2}
      >
        <h2>In-App Reporting</h2>
      </Box>
      <Box
        ref={sisenseRef}
        id="sisense-container"
        className="sisense-demo"
      ></Box>
    </>
  );
};
```